# What would be good table design for recording attendance of students

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I saw the other database design topics for same, but they were like recording a single attendance for a day.

I want to record attendance of students for 5 subjects each day, and then retrieve it on my php page where student can enter his roll number and attendance will be shown to him as 15/20 and like that against 5 subjects in 5 lines. Where 15 is the total number of classes he attended and 20 is total number of classes held.

I know that better approach to this would be making different tables for different entities, but I m not able to come up with a design.

What I thought of is:

A table containing colums:

id, student name, date, subject, subject class(boolean, was lecture for this subject held on this date), Attendance (Boolean, did the student attend or not)

Or
Have 5 different tables for 5 subjects like:
Lets say for Physics 
Columns:
id, student name, date, attended

But both these tables will have a lot of redundant values. Lets say for second table, for attendance of 3 days for 70 students, each name will be repeated thrice and 3 dates will be repeated 70 times.

Any better approach?

P.S. I do not know foreign keys or any other concept in MySQL, and yet too naive to learn it and implement it in a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following structure:

Table for Students

1. ID - unique ID for each user
2. Surname
3. First name - this can be added to the Surname value to generate the full name where appropriate

Table for Classes

1. ID - unique ID for each class
2. Class - name of the class, e.g. Physics

Table for Lessons

1. ID of lesson
2. Datetime of lesson - the date and time the lesson starts (you can add in the leaving time once the data has been extracted)
3. ClassID - the ID of the class referred to

Table for Attendance

1. ID
2. ID of Lesson
3. StudentID - the ID number of the student being referred to
4. Attendance - the attendance of this student (e.g. P=present, A=absent, L=late)

You can then map these tables together using the information in the final two tables (*Table for Lessons* and *Table for Attendance*).

---

Alternatively you could merge *Table for Lessons* and *Table for Attendance* together to form:

Table for Attendance and Lessons

1. ID of lesson
2. Datetime of lesson - the date and time the lesson starts (you can add in the leaving time once the data has been extracted)
3. ClassID - the ID of the class referred to
4. StudentID - the ID number of the student being referred to
5. Attendance - the attendance of this student (e.g. P=present, A=absent, L=late)

Comment: I would take student ID and attendence out of the lesson table, and have a separate Attendence table that has a FK to Lesson, with StudentID and AttendenceType instead. That way the program can actually show the current active lessons and allow them to be edited.

Comment: Good idea, I have improved the answer with that information

Comment: I like your design but you see, redundancy is still there in the last table. Columns would Conatin same values for all students...
But I guess that is the only Approach! :)
Thank you for your time. Appreciated.